# Is loading data in viewDidLoad too late to display it in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

Where do you usually load data when using a UIViewController?

When I say "loading data" I mean: API calls to fetch it and its manipulation.

Do you load it in the view controller initializer, or load it before to initialize it and pass it? Or do you add the code to viewDidLoad?

Also, what about the data for the rootViewController? The one that initialises from storyboard when you launch the app?

Comment: `rootViewController` has a class name that contains `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Instead of viewDidLoad you can write DB or API call in loadView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you load it in the view controller initializer, or load it before to initialize it and pass it? Or do you add the code to viewDidLoad?

Usually this done inisde `viewDidLoad` e.x in MVC you call the controller to load the data and refresh the contents of the vc like table/collection , regarding sending data case this known as dependency injection

> Also, what about the data for the rootViewController?

`rootViewController` is same as any other vc

Comment: This is also what I thought, however I've been told that I'm loading data is in the wrong position, so I might get empty screens

Comment: You can make api calls or db query or what so ever in the viewDidLoad function. But remember, if you don’t want to compromise on the user experience you should never block the main thread. You can initialize your data fetch in the viewDidLoad function and let the fetch happen in thread other than main. Once data fetch completed, you can refresh the view in main thread. This way, you can ensure you don’t compromise on user experience.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan Indeed I'm not blocking the main thread, however I've been told that loading data in viewDidLoad could result in empty view controllers displayed on the screen.

Comment: Unless you block the main thread or your data fetch takes long time you won’t see empty view controller if you initiate data loading in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I guess what I meant is the loading time indeed... but since I run the app and there is no visible delay or empty screen, I was surprise by such statement

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me suggest not to have data loading code in ViewController if your app is not very very simple. It would be a better practice to have it in a separate class. Check out MVP or VIPER design patterns for more info.

As for *when* to load your data (after view loaded or before) is more of a UX decision.
If you start loading after, of course, screen might be empty for a while, it would be good to have some loading indicator on the screen so that users do not get confused. Whether users will see empty screens often or not depends on whether you store your loaded data permanently (in a local DB), have some run time cache, or non of that. If you have some caching, empty screen will be visible just once, because if data is loaded and cached you will show that and update the screen after new data is received.

You can also start loading data before view is loaded (in loadView()) or may load some minimal data for the views which are not visible (so that they are not completely empty when opened) and then load full data after view is loaded.

Any approach you choose is highly dependent on what kind of user experience do you want to provide, also on how long it takes to load your data.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in one line is viewididload but below is the actual structural method.

So for this you can have multiple answer the most popular answer for these days would be using MVC/MVVM. So let's discus about MVVM with delegate/protocol

Model - your data.

View model - here you initialize/modify/handle your data.

Viewcontroller - viewdidload - here you can initialize your view model and interact with the data that can be provided by view model with the help of delegate-protocol mechanism.

Comment: Ok, but the question regardless of the model is: do you initialize your model (in your case viewmodel) in "viewDidLoad"? Thus, data loading is happening after viewDidLoad is called?

Comment: we don't initialize in our of viewdidload but in the vc class itself out of any function or the other way is to initialize where you are initiating this vc which could be from previous/parent vc.

Comment: ok got it. So this is not happening in viewDidLoad at all, at initialisation time or by setting a property/calling a function from the parent, right after initialising it

Comment: Correct! You got it.